# How to run a procedure immediately when 'view report' is clicked in ssrs?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a `ssrs report` which has many `tables`. These tables fetch the data from database tables with the defined `datasets`. Now **before my report fetches the data from the dataset, it is really important to run a procedure based on user input into my report parameter**. How can I achieve this?

Note: As of now I wrote a EXEC PROC statement in one of my datasets. I am now clicking the 'View report' twice to see the expected results.

Comment: can you please elaborate more on this part `before my report fetches the data from the dataset, it is really important to run a procedure based on user input into my report parameter`

Comment: have you tried using  Begin EXEC PROC...  end begin select field from... end ?

Comment: The datasets are now connected to the specfic tables. These tables needs to be populated with new records which will be generated once my PROC runs which will be based on the user input in my report parameter. @TheGameiswar

Comment: will try now @Kostya

Comment: it spoils the existing result itself @Kostya

Comment: Change the stored procedure to include your report SQL as a select statement at the end. Then change your SSRS report to be a stored procedure based report and voila!

Comment: This will not work out... this procedure already used to load many tables..... I cannot modify that or include select statement in that...@Anand

Comment: Then create a new stored procedure, call the original stored procedure first and then your report SQL from the new stored procedure. Improvise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, SSRS processes all the datasets in parallel. There is an option called "Use single transaction when processing the queries" which makes it evaluate the datasets one at a time. So the first procedure has to finish before it will move on. This setting is in the Data Source properties. The datasets will be processed in the order you added them, so you may have to rearrange them to make your procedure be first.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific? I have used this in the past to show results before and after a procedure is run in the same report. Have you confirmed the order of the datasets in the .rdl?

Comment: I have many datasets in my report.... as you told I placed my exec Proc in my first dataset...